# Pandas to CSV & asyncio

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to write a CSV from a Pandas DataFrame that is continuously appended with data from an exchange (CCXT library, using Asyncio).
The problem I face is that my CSV is only written at the end of the GetThicker function (in this case, never). How do I write this CSV line by line?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd

root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
sys.path.append(root + '/python')

import ccxt.async_support as ccxt  # noqa: E402

def WriteCSV(df):
     df.to_csv('Test2.csv',columns=['Date & Time', 'Closing Price'])
     #print(df)

async def GetThicker(symbol):

    exchange = ccxt.binance({
        'enableRateLimit': True,  # this option enables the built-in rate limiter
    })
    data = {'Date & Time' : 0,'Closing Price':0}
    index = 0

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns={'Date & Time','Closing Price'}, index=[index])
    df.index.name = 'ID'
    while True:
        #print(exchange.iso8601(exchange.milliseconds()), 'fetching', symbol, 'ticker from', exchange.name)
        try:
            ticker = await exchange.fetch_ticker(symbol)
            df.loc[index,'Closing Price'] = ticker['close']
            df.loc[index,'Date & Time'] = ticker['datetime']
            print(ticker['datetime'],'-',ticker['close'])
            WriteCSV(df)
            index +=1
        except ccxt.RequestTimeout as e:
            print('[' + type(e).__name__ + ']')
            print(str(e)[0:200])
            # will retry
        except ccxt.DDoSProtection as e:
            print('[' + type(e).__name__ + ']')
            print(str(e.args)[0:200])
            # will retry
        except ccxt.ExchangeNotAvailable as e:
            print('[' + type(e).__name__ + ']')
            print(str(e.args)[0:200])
            # will retry
        except ccxt.ExchangeError as e:
            print('[' + type(e).__name__ + ']')
            print(str(e)[0:200])
            break  # won't retry

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(GetThicker('BTC/USDT'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



#asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(GetThicker('BTC/USDT'))
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you create the exchange instance inside a running coroutine, you also need to pass the `asyncio_loop` to its constructor.

The `asyncio_loop` param is optional only if the exchange instance is created outside of async context.

If the exchange is instantiated inside an async context, like in your case, it has to know which async loop to use.

See edited code and comments below:

```
import asyncio
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd

root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
sys.path.append(root + '/python')

import ccxt.async_support as ccxt  # noqa: E402

def WriteCSV(df):
    # print(df)
    df.to_csv('Test2.csv',columns=['Date & Time', 'Closing Price'])

async def GetThicker(loop, symbol):  # ←------ HERE

    exchange = ccxt.binance({
        'enableRateLimit': True,  # this option enables the built-in rate limiter
        'asyncio_loop': loop,   # ←------ HERE
    })
    data = {'Date & Time' : 0,'Closing Price':0}
    index = 0
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns={'Date & Time','Closing Price'}, index=[index])
    df.index.name = 'ID'
    while True:
        try:
            ticker = await exchange.fetch_ticker(symbol)
            df.loc[index,'Closing Price'] = ticker['close']
            df.loc[index,'Date & Time'] = ticker['datetime']
            print(ticker['datetime'],'-',ticker['close'])
            WriteCSV(df)
            index +=1
        except ccxt.NetworkError as e:
            print('[' + type(e).__name__ + ']')
            print(str(e.args)[0:200])
            # will retry
        except ccxt.ExchangeError as e:
            print('[' + type(e).__name__ + ']')
            print(str(e)[0:200])
            break  # won't retry

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    symbol = 'BTC/USDT'
    loop.run_until_complete(GetThicker(loop, symbol))  # ←------ HERE

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```